# Como firmar un .pkg con un certificado de apple?

Tags: macos, pkg

He creado un instalador `.pkg` con la herramienta [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html), pero al distribuirlo en las demas mac no deja instalarlo porque solo permite appstore y desarrolladores identificados, ya tengo mi certificado, mas no se como firmarlo, como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la terminal con la herramienta de linea de comandos `productsign` de Apple que viene con `XCODE`, puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera:

`productsign --sign com.tu.id.cert tuRutaAl.pkg tuProductoFinal.pgk`

Puedes ver tambien la documentacion de productsign de Apple Developer [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productsign.1.html)